# How to use Teams AI Using other language models and hosts with url

Tags: microsoft-teams

Anyone has any idea how to modify Teams AI codes for OpenAIModel
Link to what Microsoft has: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/teams%20conversational%20ai/how-conversation-ai-get-started?tabs=javascript4%2Cjavascript1%2Cjavascript3%2Cjavascript2#create-ai-components

```
// Create AI components
const model = new OpenAIModel({
    // OpenAI Support
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_KEY!,
    defaultModel: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',

    // Azure OpenAI Support
    azureApiKey: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_KEY!,
    azureDefaultDeployment: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    azureEndpoint: process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT!,
    azureApiVersion: '2023-03-15-preview',

    // Request logging
    logRequests: true
});
```

to fit with the original OpenAI library? It is kinda confusing as it will violate the next instance use

```
const planner = new ActionPlanner({
    model,
    prompts,
    defaultPrompt: 'chat'
});
```

that model with type OpenAI doesn't support.

code from OpenAI I want to use:

```
from openai import OpenAI
openai_api_key = "EMPTY"
openai_api_base = "http://localhost:8000/v1"
client = OpenAI(
    api_key=openai_api_key,
    base_url=openai_api_base,
)
completion = client.completions.create(model="facebook/opt-125m",
                                      prompt="San Francisco is a")
print("Completion result:", completion)
```

Comment: Could you please share the exact error that you are facing. Also, please confirm if model="facebook/opt-125m" is part of Open AI?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this sample code and comment lines related to Azure Open AI support: https://github.com/microsoft/teams-ai/blob/main/js/samples/04.ai.a.teamsChefBot/src/index.ts#L90

You can also follow this guide as well:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/teams%20conversational%20ai/conversation-ai-quick-start?pivots=qs-javascript